# Bind same controller from multiple Service Providers, with different parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, service-provider

I am creating various Laravel packages, each with their own Service Provider.

A lot of them will need to a bind a Controller from another package I made, but call it with unique parameters.

The issue I'm getting is that, even with the bind in the boot method, App B is binding the controller with the bind from App A's Service Provider.

Is there a way to segregate the binds, so App A binds the controller with it's parameters, and App B binds it with it's own parameters?

Comment: Is [Contextual Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#contextual-binding) a solution?

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. The examples don't really match up with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So my workaround for now, is when I'm doing the binding, I wrap them in an IF statement to check the host (sub domain) the request comes from.